# React native expo read file as binary

Tags: react-native, expo, base64, buffer

I am currently doing the following:

```
const fileInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(uri)
const CHUNK_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024
const fileSize = fileInfo.size

const partSize = Math.min(CHUNK_SIZE, fileSize)
const parts = Math.ceil(fileSize/partSize)

let position = 0
let partsComplete = 0

while (position < parts) {
  const length = Math.min(CHUNK_SIZE, fileSize - partsComplete)
  const chunk = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, {
    encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
    length,
    position
  })

  position += 1
  partsComplete += length
}
```

In short, I'm using presigned urls to upload the chunks in a multipart upload. My problem is that the chunks are read as base64 encoded strings instead of binary. The videos are uploading to s3 but are corrupt / won't open. Using `readAsStringAync`, I can only use `Base64` or `UTF8`, not binary.

I was looking through the [AWS Storage library](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/lib/lib-storage/src/chunker.ts) to see how they are handling it and they use the Buffer library it seems?

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

const binaryData = Buffer.from(base64string, 'base64');
```

However, this isn't working for me. I don't want to have to buy into Amplify to use the Storage library but I'm not sure what they are doing differently to get it to work.

Any ideas on how to chunk a large file in Expo into binary?